# What is meant by $A = (A_{ij})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, notation

[image]
$Aut_{\phi}$ is a sub-group of the group of linear automorphisms $GL$. Precisely $Aut_{\phi}(V) := \{A\in GL(V) | \phi(A(v),A(v)) = \phi(v,v), \forall v \in V \}$. Here $\phi$ is the scalar product.

What is $A_{ik}$? And what is meant by $A = (A_{ij})$?

Comment: All your tags are wrong; your question is about Linear Algebra, not hyperbolic geometry or geometry. Also, what are your own thoughts about the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A_{ij}$ is the entry in the $i$-th row, $j$-th column. So the statement $A=(A_{ij})$ is simply denoting that $A$ is the matrix with the entries given by the set of values $A_{ij}$ where $1\leq i,j\leq n$.

Answer (score 2):

$A_{ij}$ represents the cells in a matrix, as shown below. Saying $A=A_{ij}$ is just clarifying that this is what is meant, e.g:
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}A_{11}&A_{12}&\cdots&A_{1n}\\\vdots&\ddots\\\\A_{n1}&&&A_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$$